# .htpasswd blocked all my css,js and images

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm using `.htpasswd` to enchance my security, but it blocked all my css,js and images.

Here's my `.htaccess`:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /my/folder/.htpass
Require valid-user
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: are you using cross site scripting ?

Comment: Does it allow you to access your public files after you've logged in? If so, it's doing what basic auth does. You may need a different solution

Comment: one more thing .. could you please try with www.yourwebite.com instead of yourwebsite.com

Comment: @Vinay sorry for asking this. I don't know much about htaccess. Did you mean i make  two *.conf files?